# How to show that the group $S_3 \times C_2$ contains three element of order 3?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, cyclic-groups

The question is,

> Which group of order $12$ is isomorphic to $S_3 \times C_2$ ?

I know that this group is a non-abelian group so it's not isomorphic to $C_4 \times C_3$ and $C_2 \times C_2 \times C_3$.

I explicitly show that this group contains three element of order 3. Is there any general way to show this one?

Comment: There is no group which possesses exactly 3 elements of order 3. Consider $S = \{x \mid x$ is of order 3$\}$. Then the function $x \mapsto x^2 : S \to S$ is a bijection $S \to S$ which is its own inverse and has no fixed points, so if $S$ is finite, then $|S|$ is even.

Comment: The group $S_3\times \Bbb Z_2$ is isomorphic to the dihedral group of order $12$.

Comment: The elements of order $3$ in $S_3 \times C_2$ are exactly $(\sigma,1)$ where $\sigma \in S_3$ has order $3$.